# Redis ZSCAN MATCH case insensitive search

Tags: redis

I have a list of places stored in Redis Sorted Set

```
ZADD PLACES 1 "The Clift Royal Sonesta Hotel"
```

Now, I want to make a case insensitive search on word "Royal". I use `ZSCAN` for this as below:

```
ZSCAN LOCATION_TRENDING 0 MATCH "*royal*" COUNT 10
```

`ZSCAN` works when I make search with "Royal" (letter **R capital**) but not with "royal" (letter **r small**).

How to make case insensitive ZSCAN match? Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: Use a Lua script to do the scan. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288229/redis-scan-matching/65298935#65298935) for an example. Except, you need to convert both key and pattern into lowercase before matching: `if string.lower(v) == string.match(string.lower(v), string.lower(ARGV[2]))`.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to scan case insensitive.
Like a workaround, you can duplicate your data with different keys and transform it to lowercase before storing.

Also, you can look through [RedisSearch module](https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch) if you need a complex search.

Comment: Yes going with RedisSearch seems like a better solution. I don't want to lowercase tricks. In RedisSearch do you know how match part of strings like search string "ot" should match "hotel" word?

Comment: You can look at this tutorial https://github.com/RediSearch/redisearch-getting-started/blob/master/docs/004-query-data.md. Bear in mind that RedisSearch is an external module and you have to load it to use it https://redis.io/topics/modules-intro.

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't work for random texts like "ot" etc, even "hote" doesn't return any results. I have already included RediSearch into my docker image so, loading module is fine.