# redis - HSCAN MATCH only "first level"

Tags: redis

I'm using Redis with hashes to index real paths from file system, e.g.:

```
HSET example "/dir" "some value"
HSET example "/dir/sub-dir" "some value"
HSET example "/dir/sub-dir-2" "some value"
HSET example "/dir/sub-dir/sub-sub-dir" "some value"
HSET example "/dir/sub-dir/another-sub-sub-dir" "some value"
```

Now I need to get "directory's content". I have tried to use `HSCAN`:

```
HSCAN example 0 MATCH "/dir/*"
```

but with this I'm getting every path in this directory but I should get only:

```
/dir/sub-dir
/dir/sub-dir-2
```

Is it possible to get this via match pattern?

Comment: You can use Lua script to do more advanced pattern matching. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288229/redis-scan-matching/65298935#65298935) for reference. You should replace the pattern with: `/dir/[^\/]*$`, and also call `HSCAN` instead of `SCAN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, no, Redis' pattern matching is glob-like which doesn't allow this.

You could use a server-side [Redis Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) for this purpose though, perhaps something like this:

```lua
local key = KEYS[1]
local cur = ARGV[1]
local path = ARGV[2]
local pattern = path .. '*'
local plen = string.len(pattern)

local r = redis.call('HSCAN', key, cur, 'MATCH', pattern)
local rlen = #r[2]
while rlen > 0 do
  local f = r[2][rlen-1]
  if string.find(f, '/', plen) then
    -- Remove field and value
    for i = 0,1 do
      table.remove(r[2], rlen)
      rlen = rlen - 1
    end
  else
    rlen = rlen - 2
  end
end

return r
~/work/redis-io master*                                                                                                               15:59:55
❯ redis-cli --eval /tmp/hscanfirstlv.lua example , 0 "/dir/"
1) "0"
2) 1) "/dir/sub-dir"
   2) "some value"
   3) "/dir/sub-dir-2"
   4) "some value"
```

Execution example:

```
$ cat myscript.lua | redis-cli SCRIPT LOAD -x
"4a95e1a03bfeeb1cb9e433862dce47b63981fbdc"
$ redis-cli EVALSHA "4a95e1a03bfeeb1cb9e433862dce47b63981fbdc" 1 example 0 "/dir/"
1) "0"
2) 1) "/dir/sub-dir"
   2) "some value"
   3) "/dir/sub-dir-2"
   4) "some value"
```